# TranslateTransition does not change (X,Y) co-ordinates

Tags: javafx

While learning the ***javafx.animation*** API, I tried the following code,
which simply draws a rectangle at (100,100) and **translates** it to (200,200) in 2 seconds.

```
import javafx.animation.TranslateTransition;
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.Group;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.layout.VBox;
import javafx.scene.paint.Color;
import javafx.scene.shape.Rectangle;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javafx.util.Duration;
import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.event.EventHandler;

public class SimpleAnimation extends Application {

  @Override
  public void start(Stage stage) {
    Group root = new Group();
    Scene scene = new Scene(root, 500, 500);
    stage.setScene(scene);

    VBox vb = new VBox();

    Rectangle rect = new Rectangle (100, 100, 100, 100);
    rect.setArcHeight(50);
    rect.setArcWidth(50);
    rect.setFill(Color.VIOLET);

    final Duration SEC_2 = Duration.millis(2000);

    System.out.println("Location before relocation = "+rect.getX()+","+rect.getY()+")");

    TranslateTransition tt = new TranslateTransition(SEC_2,rect);
    tt.setByX(100f);
    tt.setByY(100f);
    tt.setOnFinished(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {
                       @Override
                       public void handle(ActionEvent event) {
                         System.out.println("Location after relocation = " + rect.getX() + "," + rect.getY() + ")");
                       }
                     });
    tt.play();

    vb.getChildren().add(rect);

        scene.setRoot(vb);
        stage.show();
      }

      public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
      }
    }
```

After this translationTransition, the rectangle is expected to have the (x,y) coordinates as **(200,200)** right?
To check this, I tried to print the coordinates in the **OnFinished()** event handler.
Don't know why it still prints **(100,100)** ?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the [Javadocs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/animation/TranslateTransition.html):

> This Transition creates a move/translate animation that spans its
>   duration. This is done by updating the translateX, translateY and
>   translateZ variables of the node at regular interval.

So if you check the `translateX` and `translateY` properties at the end of the transition, you will find they are both equal to `100`; i.e. the rectangle has been translated from its original position by `100` units in both directions.

Depending on exactly what you are wanting to do, you can either work with the `translateX` and `translateY` properties, or work with the [`boundsInParent`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/Node.html#boundsInParentProperty) property, which gives the bounds of a node in its parent's coordinate system (and thus includes any transforms, such as the translation).

If you prefer to have the `x` and `y` properties of the `Rectangle` change directly from the animation, use a [`Timeline`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/animation/Timeline.html), which allows you to specify the property (or properties) that change:

```
import javafx.animation.KeyFrame;
import javafx.animation.KeyValue;
import javafx.animation.Timeline;
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.event.EventHandler;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.layout.VBox;
import javafx.scene.paint.Color;
import javafx.scene.shape.Rectangle;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javafx.util.Duration;

public class SimpleAnimation extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) {

        VBox vb = new VBox();

        Rectangle rect = new Rectangle(100, 100, 100, 100);
        rect.setManaged(false);
        rect.setArcHeight(50);
        rect.setArcWidth(50);
        rect.setFill(Color.VIOLET);

        final Duration SEC_2 = Duration.millis(2000);

        System.out.println("Location before relocation = " + rect.getX() + ","
                + rect.getY() + ")");

        Timeline timeline = new Timeline();

        KeyFrame end = new KeyFrame(SEC_2,
                new KeyValue(rect.xProperty(), 200),
                new KeyValue(rect.yProperty(), 200));

        timeline.getKeyFrames().add(end);

        timeline.setOnFinished(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {
            @Override
            public void handle(ActionEvent event) {
                System.out.println("Location after relocation = " + rect.getX()
                        + "," + rect.getY() + ")");
            }
        });
        timeline.play();

        vb.getChildren().add(rect);

        Scene scene = new Scene(vb, 500, 500);
        stage.setScene(scene);

        stage.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

Note that for this to work, I added the call `rect.setManaged(false)`. Since you have the `Rectangle` in a `VBox`, which manages layout of its child nodes, changing the `x` and `y` properties will have no effect otherwise. (The other option would be to replace the `VBox` with a `Pane`, which doesn't manage placement of its child nodes.)

Comment: The project in which I was gonna implement animations, uses getX() and getY() everywhere to get location of a node. Is it possible to update x to (getX()+getTranslateX()) and set translateX to 0? Otherwise I'll have to replace every occurrence of getX() with (getX()+getTranslateX()) in the code. (and getY likewise)

Comment: You could do that, probably better just to use  Timeline to directly manipulate the x and y properties in place of the TranslateTransition though.

Comment: Tried Timeline too. Turns out Timeline  also update translateX & translateY only.

Comment: Rishav, if your Timeline is only updating translateX & translateY, then that is because that it what you told it to do.  Timelines can certainly update different properties such as the X and Y properties of a rectangle if that is what you tell them to do.

Comment: I updated the answer to show an example of using a `Timeline`; as @jewelsea points out, with a `Timeline` you have to declare the properties that will be modified during the animation.

Answer (score 1):

When the animation is finished, move the animated node to the translation co-ordinates:

```
tt.setOnFinished(event -> {
    // The transition works by manipulating translation values,
    // After the transition is complete, move the node to the new location
    // and zero the translation after relocating the node.
    rect.setX(rect.getX() + rect.getTranslateX());
    rect.setY(rect.getY() + rect.getTranslateY());
    rect.setTranslateX(0);
    rect.setTranslateY(0);
});
```

Also you place your Rectangle in a VBox, don't do that if you want the X&Y co-ordinates of the rectangle to mean anything.  A VBox is a layout manager and will ignore X&Y co-ordinates of the rectangle (because it will make everything inside it layout vertically).  Instead perform your animation in a Parent which does not perform layout (e.g. a Group or a Pane).

Executable sample:

```
import javafx.animation.TranslateTransition;
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.*;
import javafx.scene.paint.Color;
import javafx.scene.shape.Rectangle;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javafx.util.Duration;

public class SimpleAnimation extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) {
        Rectangle rect = new Rectangle(100, 100, 100, 100);
        rect.setArcHeight(50);
        rect.setArcWidth(50);
        rect.setFill(Color.VIOLET);

        System.out.println("Location before relocation = " + rect.getX() + "," + rect.getY() + ")");

        TranslateTransition tt = new TranslateTransition(
              Duration.seconds(2), 
              rect
        );

        tt.setByX(100f);
        tt.setByY(100f);
        tt.setOnFinished(event -> {
            rect.setX(rect.getX() + rect.getTranslateX());
            rect.setY(rect.getY() + rect.getTranslateY());
            rect.setTranslateX(0);
            rect.setTranslateY(0);

            System.out.println("Location after relocation = " + rect.getX() + "," + rect.getY() + ")");
        });

        tt.play();

        Scene scene = new Scene(new Group(rect), 500, 500);
        stage.setScene(scene);

        stage.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```