# Animation depends on previous animations

Tags: animation, javafx, sequential

I am trying to set node animation, that depends on previous animations of that node as well as other nodes.
To demonstrate the issue I'll use a simple `Pane` with 4 `Label` children:

[image]

The main class as well as the model and view classes:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.concurrent.CountDownLatch; 
import javafx.animation.TranslateTransition;
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.beans.property.SimpleObjectProperty;
import javafx.beans.value.ChangeListener;
import javafx.geometry.Point2D;
import javafx.geometry.Pos;
import javafx.scene.Node;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.layout.BorderPane;
import javafx.scene.layout.HBox;
import javafx.scene.layout.Pane;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javafx.util.Duration;

public final class Puzzle extends Application{

    private Controller controller;
    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) throws Exception {
        controller = new Controller();
        BorderPane root = new BorderPane(controller.getBoardPane());
        root.setTop(controller.getControlPane());
        Scene scene = new Scene(root);
        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) { launch();}
}

class View{

    private static final double size = 70;
    private static Duration animationDuration = Duration.millis(600);
    private int[][] cellModels;
    private Node[][] cellNodes;
    private CountDownLatch latch;
    Button play = new Button("Play");
    private Pane board, control = new HBox(play);;

    View(Model model) {
        cellModels = model.getCellModels();
        cellNodes = new Node[cellModels.length][cellModels[0].length];
        makeBoardPane();
        ((HBox) control).setAlignment(Pos.CENTER_RIGHT);
    }

    private void makeBoardPane() {

        board = new Pane();
        for (int row = 0; row < cellModels.length ; row ++ ) {
            for (int col = 0; col < cellModels[row].length ; col ++ ) {

               Label label = new Label(String.valueOf(cellModels[row][col]));
               label.setPrefSize(size, size);
               Point2D location = getLocationByRowCol(row, col);
               label.setLayoutX(location.getX());
               label.setLayoutY(location.getY());
               label.setStyle("-fx-border-color:blue");
               label.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);
               cellNodes[row][col] = label;
               board.getChildren().add(label);
            }
        }
    }

    synchronized void updateCell(int id, int row, int column) {

        if(latch !=null) {
            try {
                latch.await();
            } catch (InterruptedException ex) { ex.printStackTrace();}
        }
        latch = new CountDownLatch(1);

        Node node = getNodesById(id).get(0);
        Point2D newLocation = getLocationByRowCol(row, column);
        Point2D moveNodeTo = node.parentToLocal(newLocation );

        TranslateTransition transition = new TranslateTransition(animationDuration, node);
        transition.setFromX(0); transition.setFromY(0);
        transition.setToX(moveNodeTo.getX());
        transition.setToY(moveNodeTo.getY());

        //set animated node layout to the translation co-ordinates:
        //https://stackoverflow.com/a/30345420/3992939
        transition.setOnFinished(ae -> {
            node.setLayoutX(node.getLayoutX() + node.getTranslateX());
            node.setLayoutY(node.getLayoutY() + node.getTranslateY());
            node.setTranslateX(0);
            node.setTranslateY(0);
            latch.countDown();
        });
        transition.play();
    }

    private List<Node> getNodesById(int...ids) {

        List<Node> nodes = new ArrayList<>();
        for(Node node : board.getChildren()) {
            if(!(node instanceof Label)) { continue; }
            for(int id : ids) {
                if(((Label)node).getText().equals(String.valueOf(id))) {
                    nodes.add(node);
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
        return nodes ;
    }

    private Point2D getLocationByRowCol(int row, int col) {
        return new Point2D(size * col, size * row);
    }

    Pane getBoardPane() { return board; }
    Pane getControlPane() { return control;}
    Button getPlayBtn() {return play ;}
}

class Model{

    private int[][] cellModels = new int[][] { {0,1}, {2,3} };
    private SimpleObjectProperty<int[][]> cellModelsProperty =
            cellModelsProperty = new SimpleObjectProperty<>(cellModels);

    void addChangeListener(ChangeListener<int[][]> listener) {
        cellModelsProperty.addListener(listener);
    }

    int[][] getCellModels() {
        return  (cellModelsProperty == null) ? null : cellModelsProperty.get();
    }

    void setCellModels(int[][] cellModels) {
        cellModelsProperty.set(cellModels);
    }
}
```

and the controller class:

```
import javafx.beans.value.ChangeListener;
import javafx.beans.value.ObservableValue;
import javafx.scene.layout.Pane;

class Controller {

    private View view ;
    private Model model;


    Controller() {
        model = new Model();
        model.addChangeListener(getModelCangeListener());//observe model changes
        view = new View(model);
        view.getPlayBtn().setOnAction( a -> shuffle());  //animation works fine
        //view.getPlayBtn().setOnAction( a -> IntStream.
        //        range(0,4).forEach( (i)-> shuffle())); //messes the animation
    }

    private ChangeListener<int[][]> getModelCangeListener() {

        return  (ObservableValue<? extends int[][]> observable,
                int[][] oldValue, int[][] newValue)-> {
                    for (int row = 0; row < newValue.length ; row++) {
                        for (int col = 0; col < newValue[row].length ; col++) {
                            if(newValue[row][col] != oldValue[row][col]) {
                                final int fRow = row, fCol = col;
                                new Thread( () -> view.updateCell(
                                    newValue[fRow][fCol], fRow, fCol)).start();
                            }
                        }
                    }
                };
    }

    void shuffle() {
        int[][] modelData = model.getCellModels();
        int rows = modelData.length, columns = modelData[0].length;
        int[][] newModelData = new int[rows][columns];
        for (int row = 0; row < rows ; row ++) {
            for (int col = 0; col < columns ; col ++) {
                int colIndex = ((col+1) < columns ) ? col + 1  : 0;
                int rowIndex =  ((col+1) < columns ) ?  row : ((row + 1) < rows) ? row +1 : 0;
                newModelData[row][col] = modelData[rowIndex][colIndex];
            }
        }

        model.setCellModels(newModelData);
    }

    Pane getBoardPane() { return view.getBoardPane(); }

    Pane getControlPane() { return view.getControlPane(); }
}
```

Play button handler changes the model data (see `shuffle()`), the change triggers `ChangeListener`. The `ChangeListener` animates each changed label by invoking `view.updateCell(..)` on a separate thread. This all works as expected. 
The problem starts when I try to run a few consecutive model updates (`shuffle()`). To simulate it I change

```
view.getPlayBtn().setOnAction( a -> shuffle());
```

with

```
view.getPlayBtn().setOnAction( a -> IntStream.range(0,4).forEach( (i)-> shuffle()));
```

which messes the animation (it plays in wrong order and ends up in wrong positions). 
This does **not** come as a surprise: to work properly animations have to be played in a certain order: a label should be re-animated only after all four labels finished their previous animation. 
The code posted runs each update on a thread, so execution order is not guaranteed.
 
 
My **question** is what is the right way to implement the needed sequence of multiple nodes and multiple animations ?

I looked at [SequentialTransition](https://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/animation/SequentialTransition.html) but I couldn't figure out how it can be used to overcome the issue in question. 
I did come up with a solution which I will post as an answer, because of the length of this post, and because I don't think the solution is good.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code does not adhere to the seperation of concerns principle. (Or at least you don't do it well.)

The animation should be done by the view and the view alone instead of collaborating between the controller and the view. Put all the animations for scheduling the animations in the `View` class.

`SequentialTransition` could wrap multiple animations in a single animation that plays them sequentially, but it shouldn't be the controller's concern to do this.

```
public class View {

    private static final double SIZE = 70;
    private static final Duration ANIMATION_DURATION = Duration.millis(600);

    private final Map<Integer, Label> labelsById = new HashMap<>(); // stores labels by id
    private final Button play = new Button("Play");
    private Pane board;
    private final HBox control;

    private final Timeline animation;
    private final LinkedList<ElementPosition> pendingAnimations = new LinkedList<>(); // stores parameter combination for update calls

    private Node animatedNode;

    public View(int[][] cellModels) { // we don't really need the whole model here
        makeBoardPane(cellModels);

        this.control = new HBox(play);
        control.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER_RIGHT);

        final DoubleProperty interpolatorValue = new SimpleDoubleProperty();

        animation = new Timeline(
                new KeyFrame(Duration.ZERO, evt -> {
                    ElementPosition ePos = pendingAnimations.removeFirst();
                    animatedNode = labelsById.get(ePos.id);

                    Point2D newLocation = getLocationByRowCol(ePos.row, ePos.column);

                    // create binding for layout pos
                    animatedNode.layoutXProperty().bind(
                            interpolatorValue.multiply(newLocation.getX() - animatedNode.getLayoutX())
                                    .add(animatedNode.getLayoutX()));
                    animatedNode.layoutYProperty().bind(
                            interpolatorValue.multiply(newLocation.getY() - animatedNode.getLayoutY())
                                    .add(animatedNode.getLayoutY()));
                }, new KeyValue(interpolatorValue, 0d)),
                new KeyFrame(ANIMATION_DURATION, evt -> {
                    interpolatorValue.set(1);

                    // remove bindings
                    animatedNode.layoutXProperty().unbind();
                    animatedNode.layoutYProperty().unbind();

                    animatedNode = null;

                    if (pendingAnimations.isEmpty()) {
                        // abort, if no more animations are pending
                        View.this.animation.stop();
                    }
                }, new KeyValue(interpolatorValue, 1d)));
        animation.setCycleCount(Animation.INDEFINITE);
    }

    private void makeBoardPane(int[][] cellModels) {
        board = new Pane();
        for (int row = 0; row < cellModels.length; row++) {
            for (int col = 0; col < cellModels[row].length; col++) {
                Point2D location = getLocationByRowCol(row, col);
                int id = cellModels[row][col];

                Label label = new Label(Integer.toString(id));
                label.setPrefSize(SIZE, SIZE);
                label.setLayoutX(location.getX());
                label.setLayoutY(location.getY());
                label.setStyle("-fx-border-color:blue");
                label.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);

                labelsById.put(id, label);

                board.getChildren().add(label);
            }
        }
    }

    private static class ElementPosition {

        private final int id;
        private final int row;
        private final int column;

        public ElementPosition(int id, int row, int column) {
            this.id = id;
            this.row = row;
            this.column = column;
        }

    }

    public void updateCell(int id, int row, int column) {
        pendingAnimations.add(new ElementPosition(id, row, column));
        animation.play();
    }

    private static Point2D getLocationByRowCol(int row, int col) {
        return new Point2D(SIZE * col, SIZE * row);
    }

    public Pane getBoard() {
        return board;
    }

    public Pane getControlPane() {
        return control;
    }

    public Button getPlayBtn() {
        return play;
    }
}
```

Usage example with reduced complexity:

```
private int[][] oldValue;

@Override
public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
    List<Integer> values = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(0, 1, 2, 3));
    oldValue = new int[][]{{0, 1}, {2, 3}};
    View view = new View(oldValue);
    Button btn = new Button("Shuffle");

    btn.setOnAction((ActionEvent event) -> {
        Collections.shuffle(values);
        int[][] newValue = new int[2][2];
        for (int i = 0; i < 2 * 2; i++) {
            newValue[i / 2][i % 2] = values.get(i);
        }
        System.out.println(values);

        for (int row = 0; row < newValue.length; row++) {
            for (int col = 0; col < newValue[row].length; col++) {
                if (newValue[row][col] != oldValue[row][col]) {
                    view.updateCell(newValue[row][col], row, col);
                }
            }
        }
        oldValue = newValue;
    });

    Scene scene = new Scene(new BorderPane(view.getBoard(), null, view.getControlPane(), btn, null));

    primaryStage.setScene(scene);
    primaryStage.show();
}
```

Comment: Thank you @fabian for you answer. It run it and it seems to do what I need. I'll have to get better understanding of `TimeLine`. 2 notes:  1. My compiler complains about `View.this.animation.stop();` 
 (The blank final field animation may not have been initialized) . I had to remove the final.  2. "Put all the animations for scheduling the animations in the View" aren't they all in `View` ? The controller processes the change in the model and breaks it into "steps" to be View needs to implement (animate). Since these steps are not view dependent  is it wrong to have them in the Controller ?

Comment: @c0der When testing the code javac did not complain about the `View.this.animation` part. As for 2.: You're using `Thread`s because of an implementation detail in `View`. Furthermore you've got a synchronized method blocking for quite some time. Both require great amout of consideration when using the class.

Answer (score 0):

The solution I came up with involved controlling the execution order of the updating threads. 
Todo it I changed the controller class by implementing an inner class based on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23097860/3992939)
so answer. See `UpdateView` in the following code.
I also modified `getModelCangeListener()` to use  `UpdateView`:

```
import java.util.stream.IntStream; 
import javafx.beans.value.ChangeListener;
import javafx.beans.value.ObservableValue;
import javafx.scene.layout.Pane;

class Controller {   
    private View view ;
    private Model model;
    private static int threadNumber = 0, threadAllowedToRun = 0;
    private static final Object myLock = new Object();

    Controller() {
        model = new Model();
        model.addChangeListener(getModelCangeListener());//observe model changes
        view = new View(model);
        view.getPlayBtn().setOnAction( a -> IntStream.
                                          range(0,4).forEach( (i)-> shuffle())); 
    }

    private ChangeListener<int[][]> getModelCangeListener() {

        return  (ObservableValue<? extends int[][]> observable,
                int[][] oldValue, int[][] newValue)-> {
                    for (int row = 0; row < newValue.length ; row++) {
                        for (int col = 0; col < newValue[row].length ; col++) {
                            if(newValue[row][col] != oldValue[row][col]) {
                                final int fRow = row, fCol = col;
                                new Thread( new UpdateView(
                                        newValue[fRow][fCol], fRow, fCol)).start();
                            }
                        }
                    }
                };
    }

    private void shuffle() {
        int[][] modelData = model.getCellModels();
        int rows = modelData.length, columns = modelData[0].length;
        int[][] newModelData = new int[rows][columns];
        for (int row = 0; row < rows ; row ++) {
            for (int col = 0; col < columns ; col ++) {
                int colIndex = ((col+1) < columns ) ? col + 1  : 0;
                int rowIndex =  ((col+1) < columns ) ?  row : ((row + 1) < rows) ? row +1 : 0;
                newModelData[row][col] = modelData[rowIndex][colIndex];
            }
        }

        model.setCellModels(newModelData);
    }

    Pane getBoardPane() { return view.getBoardPane(); }

    Pane getControlPane() { return view.getControlPane(); }

    //https://stackoverflow.com/a/23097860/3992939
    class UpdateView implements Runnable {

        private int id, row, col, threadID;

        UpdateView(int id, int row, int col) {
            this.id = id;  this.row = row;  this.col = col;
            threadID = threadNumber++;
        }

        @Override
        public void run() {
            synchronized (myLock) {
                while (threadID != threadAllowedToRun) {
                    try {
                        myLock.wait();
                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {}
                }
                view.updateCell(id, row, col);
                threadAllowedToRun++;
                myLock.notifyAll();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

While it as a possible solution I think a solution based on JavaFx own tools is preferable.

Answer (score 0):

The following answer is based [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50077344/3992939) answer. I refactored it, breaking it into smaller, more verbose "pieces", which makes it (for me) easier to understand.
I am posting it in hope it will help others as well.

```
import java.util.LinkedList;
import java.util.stream.IntStream;
import javafx.animation.Animation;
import javafx.animation.KeyFrame;
import javafx.animation.KeyValue;
import javafx.animation.Timeline;
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.beans.property.DoubleProperty;
import javafx.beans.property.SimpleDoubleProperty;
import javafx.beans.property.SimpleObjectProperty;
import javafx.beans.value.ChangeListener;
import javafx.beans.value.ObservableValue;
import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.event.EventHandler;
import javafx.geometry.Point2D;
import javafx.geometry.Pos;
import javafx.scene.Node;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.layout.BorderPane;
import javafx.scene.layout.HBox;
import javafx.scene.layout.Pane;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javafx.util.Duration;

public final class Puzzle extends Application{

    private Controller controller;
    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) throws Exception {
        controller = new Controller();
        BorderPane root = new BorderPane(controller.getBoardPane());
        root.setTop(controller.getControlPane());
        Scene scene = new Scene(root);
        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) { launch();}
}

class Controller {

    private View view ;
    private Model model;

    Controller() {
        model = new Model();
        model.addChangeListener(getModelCangeListener());//observe model changes
        view = new View(model);
        view.getPlayBtn().setOnAction( a -> IntStream.
                                range(0,4).forEach( (i)-> shuffle()));
    }

    private ChangeListener<int[][]> getModelCangeListener() {

        return  (ObservableValue<? extends int[][]> observable,
            int[][] oldValue, int[][] newValue)-> {
                for (int row = 0; row < newValue.length ; row++) {
                    for (int col = 0; col < newValue[row].length ; col++) {
                        if(newValue[row][col] != oldValue[row][col]) {
                            view.updateCell(newValue[row][col], row, col);
                        }
                    }
                }
            };
    }

    private void shuffle() {
        int[][] modelData = model.getCellModels();
        int rows = modelData.length, columns = modelData[0].length;
        int[][] newModelData = new int[rows][columns];
        for (int row = 0; row < rows ; row ++) {
            for (int col = 0; col < columns ; col ++) {
                int colIndex = ((col+1) < columns ) ? col + 1  : 0;
                int rowIndex =  ((col+1) < columns ) ?  row : ((row + 1) < rows) ? row +1 : 0;
                newModelData[row][col] = modelData[rowIndex][colIndex];
            }
        }
        model.setCellModels(newModelData);
    }

    Pane getBoardPane() { return view.getBoardPane(); }

    Pane getControlPane() { return view.getControlPane(); }
}

class View{

    private final Timeline timeLineAnimation;// private final Timeline timeLineAnimation;
    private final LinkedList<ElementPosition> pendingAnimations = new LinkedList<>(); // stores parameter combination for update calls
    private static final Duration ANIMATION_DURATION = Duration.millis(600);
    private static final double SIZE = 70;
    private int[][] cellModels;

    private final Button play = new Button("Play");
    private Pane board, control = new HBox(play);
    Node animatedNode;

    View(Model model) {
        cellModels = model.getCellModels();
        makeBoardPane();
        ((HBox) control).setAlignment(Pos.CENTER_RIGHT);
        timeLineAnimation = new TimeLineAnimation().get();
    }

    private void makeBoardPane() {

        board = new Pane();
        for (int row = 0; row < cellModels.length ; row ++ ) {
            for (int col = 0; col < cellModels[row].length ; col ++ ) {
               int id = cellModels[row][col];
               Label label = new Label(String.valueOf(id));
               label.setPrefSize(SIZE, SIZE);
               Point2D location = getLocationByRowCol(row, col);
               label.setLayoutX(location.getX());
               label.setLayoutY(location.getY());
               label.setStyle("-fx-border-color:blue");
               label.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);
               label.setId(String.valueOf(id));
               board.getChildren().add(label);
            }
        }
    }

    public void updateCell(int id, int row, int column) {
        pendingAnimations.add(new ElementPosition(id, row, column));
        timeLineAnimation.play();
    }

    private Node getNodeById(int id) {

        return board.getChildren().filtered(n ->
            Integer.valueOf(n.getId()) == id).get(0);
    }

    private Point2D getLocationByRowCol(int row, int col) {
        return new Point2D(SIZE * col, SIZE * row);
    }

    Pane getBoardPane() { return board; }
    Pane getControlPane() { return control;}
    Button getPlayBtn() {return play ;}

    private static class ElementPosition {

        private final int id, row, column;

        public ElementPosition(int id, int row, int column) {
            this.id = id;
            this.row = row;
            this.column = column;
        }
    }

    class TimeLineAnimation {

        private final Timeline timeLineAnimation;
        //value to be interpolated by time line
        final DoubleProperty interpolatorValue = new SimpleDoubleProperty();
        private Node animatedNode;

        TimeLineAnimation() {
            timeLineAnimation = new Timeline(getSartKeyFrame(), getEndKeyFrame());
            timeLineAnimation.setCycleCount(Animation.INDEFINITE);
        }

        // a 0 duration event, used to do the needed setup for next key frame
        private KeyFrame getSartKeyFrame() {

            //executed when key frame ends
            EventHandler<ActionEvent> onFinished = evt -> {

                //protects against "playing" when no pending animations
                if(pendingAnimations.isEmpty()) {
                    timeLineAnimation.stop();
                    return;
                };
                ElementPosition ePos = pendingAnimations.removeFirst();
                animatedNode = getNodeById(ePos.id);

                Point2D newLocation = getLocationByRowCol(ePos.row, ePos.column);

                // bind x,y layout properties interpolated property interpolation effects
                //both x and y
                animatedNode.layoutXProperty().bind(
                        interpolatorValue.multiply(newLocation.getX() - animatedNode.getLayoutX())
                                .add(animatedNode.getLayoutX()));
                animatedNode.layoutYProperty().bind(
                        interpolatorValue.multiply(newLocation.getY() - animatedNode.getLayoutY())
                                .add(animatedNode.getLayoutY()));
            };

            KeyValue startKeyValue = new KeyValue(interpolatorValue, 0d);
            return new KeyFrame(Duration.ZERO, onFinished, startKeyValue);
        }

        private KeyFrame getEndKeyFrame() {

            //executed when key frame ends
            EventHandler<ActionEvent> onFinished =evt -> {
                // remove bindings
                animatedNode.layoutXProperty().unbind();
                animatedNode.layoutYProperty().unbind();
            };

            KeyValue endKeyValue = new KeyValue(interpolatorValue, 1d);
            return new KeyFrame(ANIMATION_DURATION, onFinished, endKeyValue);
        }

        Timeline get() { return timeLineAnimation;  }
    }
}

class Model{

    private int[][] cellModels = new int[][] { {0,1}, {2,3} };
    private SimpleObjectProperty<int[][]> cellModelsProperty =
            cellModelsProperty = new SimpleObjectProperty<>(cellModels);

    void addChangeListener(ChangeListener<int[][]> listener) {
        cellModelsProperty.addListener(listener);
    }

    int[][] getCellModels() {
        return  (cellModelsProperty == null) ? null : cellModelsProperty.get();
    }

    void setCellModels(int[][] cellModels) { cellModelsProperty.set(cellModels);}
}
```

(to run copy paste the entire code into Puzzle.java)